# Flattening MultiIndex in header swaps the column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame with multiple headers:

```
    Datetime            Value
id                      a           b           c           d           e
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
1   2017-01-01 00:10:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
2   2017-01-01 00:20:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
3   2017-01-01 00:30:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
4   2017-01-01 00:40:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
```

When I pass from multiple headers to a single header, at some point the column names are swapped  and I don't know how to fix it.

```
cols = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
df.columns = [col[1] if col[0] == '' else col[0] for col in df.columns]
cols.insert(0,"Datetime")
df.columns = cols
```

This gives me swapped column names:

```
    Datetime            a           b           d           e           c
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
1   2017-01-01 00:10:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
2   2017-01-01 00:20:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
3   2017-01-01 00:30:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
4   2017-01-01 00:40:00 0.774016    1.588788    270.06055   268.9109    93060.31
```

How can I fix it?

*Update:*

```
{('Datetime', ''): {0: Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:10:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:20:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:30:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:40:00')},
 ('Value', 'a'): {0: 0.774016,
  1: 0.774016,
  2: 0.774016,
  3: 0.774016,
  4: 0.774016},
 ('Value', 'b'): {0: 1.588788,
  1: 1.588788,
  2: 1.588788,
  3: 1.588788,
  4: 1.588788},
 ('Value', 'c'): {0: 270.06055,
  1: 270.06055,
  2: 270.06055,
  3: 270.06055,
  4: 270.06055},
 ('Value', 'd'): {0: 268.9109,
  1: 268.9109,
  2: 268.9109,
  3: 268.9109,
  4: 268.9109},
 ('Value', 'e'): {0: 93060.31,
  1: 93060.31,
  2: 93060.31,
  3: 93060.31,
  4: 93060.31}}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't want this output.

Comment: You're just trying to remove `Value`? Can you include a dataframe constructor `df.head().to_dict()` MultiIndexes are hard to parse from a text dump.

Comment: Yes please with the `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: try this: `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()`

Comment: That would get rid of DateTime as well @Don'tAccept no?

Comment: @Don'tAccept: This works, but one of the columns (`Datetime`) has an empty column name. In other words, the column name `Datetime` disappears and it's just blank.

Comment: @HenryEcker Please check my update.

Comment: `df.columns=["Datetime","a","b","c","d","e"]`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas: It does not work this way. It puts `c` column as the last one, i.e. applies swapping of column names for some reason

Comment: @Fluxy, then just add that one column name separately. Since your data has required information at two levels, you need the manual work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) + [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html#pandas-dataframe-droplevel) + [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index):

```
df.set_index('Datetime', append=True).droplevel(0, 1).reset_index('Datetime')
```

```
              Datetime         a         b          c         d         e
id                                                                       
0  2017-01-01 00:00:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
1  2017-01-01 00:10:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
2  2017-01-01 00:20:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
3  2017-01-01 00:30:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
4  2017-01-01 00:40:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
```

---

Also to fix your implementation, don't insert into the list and misalign the DataFrame just do:

```
df.columns = [col[1] if col[1] else col[0] for col in df.columns]
```

```
              Datetime         a         b          c         d         e
id                                                                       
0  2017-01-01 00:00:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
1  2017-01-01 00:10:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
2  2017-01-01 00:20:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
3  2017-01-01 00:30:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
4  2017-01-01 00:40:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
```

Answer (score 2):

Bruteforce approach

```
>>> pd.concat([df[['Datetime']].droplevel(1, axis=1), df["Value"]], axis=1)
               Datetime         a         b          c         d         e
id
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
1   2017-01-01 00:10:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
2   2017-01-01 00:20:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
3   2017-01-01 00:30:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
4   2017-01-01 00:40:00  0.774016  1.588788  270.06055  268.9109  93060.31
```